# SSRS How to hide a tablix if parameter does not match column values?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to hide a tablix if a user entry text parameter (with no specified available values) does not match column values found in a column. I want to hide the tablix if it matches and show the tablix if it doesn't match any column values.

In the tablix properties I'm trying to 'Show or hide based on an expression' with the expression:

```
=iif(Parameters!IDNumberEntry.Value = Fields!IDNumber.Value,True,False)
```

and its not working. It just shows it no matter if the ID entered in the text box parameter matches values in the IDNumber column or not.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check this post https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b30d0e78-9200-45aa-93e7-f214198d3ed0/search-in-ssrs-dataset-or-ssrs-table-for-a-specific-value?forum=sqlreportingservices

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In the'Show or hide based on an expression', I used lookup to see if an ID entered in a parameter matches the ID value in a the column.

```
=iif(lookup(Parameters!IDNumberEntry.Value,Fields!IDNumber.Value,Fields!IDNumber.Value,"DataSet1")="",False,true)
```